# SSRS Parameter for Expression

Tags: reporting-services, filtering, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder3.0

I have a matrix table in Report Builder where one of the columns is calculated by an expression, namely sum(units) / sum(deliveries). I want to filter the table so that it shows only certain rows, i.e. where sum(units) / sum(deliveries) >= 30.

However, I get an error when trying to filter the matrix table directly by the above expression: A FilterExpression for the tablix 'Tablix1' includes an aggregate function.  Aggregate functions cannot be used in dataset filters or data region filters.

I wondered if there's any way around this other than writing the expression into my SQL query, as this is a rather complicated query and would take too long to explain.

I have tried writing what I would like to do into my SQL query but wasn't able to achieve this. Ideally, I need a way to do this directly in the report builder. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm don't you'll be able to do this. Personally I would always do this in SQL, it will reduce the amount of data sent to the report assuming you are grouping in the report anyway. If your query is complex, it looks like you output `units` and `deliveries` columns so wrap your query and do your calc in the outer query. `SELECT myGroupA, myGroupB, SUM(Units) as Units, SUM(Deliveries) as Deliveries, SUM(Units)/SUM(Deliveries) as AvgUnits FROM (my current query here) q GROUP BY myGroupA, MyGroupB` or along those lines.